# Default schema for a user

Tags: sql-server-2008

**Default schema for a user**. 
Its mean, whenever I execute a select query without pointing any schema, it uses the schema which is set as default (I read somewhere).

For Some reason I have change the default schema for a user. Now select statement should be point default schema, But it’s not working. Please have a look below code.

```
CREATE SCHEMA Schema_1 
CREATE SCHEMA Schema_2 
GO 
Create table Schema_1.TEST (DATA Varchar(200)) 
Create table Schema_2.TEST (DATA Varchar(200)) 
GO 
insert into Schema_1.TEST values('Schema_1 IS HERE') 
insert into Schema_2.TEST values('Schema_2 IS HERE') 
GO  

CREATE proc Schema_1.TestSP 
AS 
SELECT * FROM TEST ---[no schema name given] 
GO  

exec Schema_1.Testsp
```

After this code I have created two users `USER_1` and `USER_2`. 
`USER_1` default schema is `Schema_1` and `USER_2` default schema is `Schema_2`.

I have executed `Schema_1.Testsp` SP. It gives `Schema_1 IS HERE` 
Now I set `Schema_2` as default schema for `USER_1`  
Again, I have executed `Schema_1.Testsp` SP. It gives `Schema_1 IS HERE` 
But it need result `Schema_2 IS HERE`.

I think you got my point.

Comment: I think the user may need to reconnect to SQL Server to get the default schema reset.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the proc is running from schema1 and that is what it uses to determine the schema of any underlying objects that are not specified.